# FInding the size of the test

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions

During revision for exams I encountered this question:

Let X be a single observation from the density

$$fX(x;θ)=θx^{θ−1}; 0<x<1, θ>0$$

The test “Reject H0 if and only if X ≥ 1/2” is used to contrast $H0 : θ ≤ 1$ against $H1 :θ>1$.

**Question**: Find the size of the test.

I just wish for someone to at least give me some tips from where I can start in answering this question.

Many thanks.